# How do I only act on keyboard events no other widget wants?

Tags: gtk

My barcode scanner acts like a keyboard spouting lines of numbers. I want it to work all the time, so I don't use a text entry but connect to my window's key-press-event. Unfortunately this is also emitted when other text entries have the focus. AFAIK because windows receive events first, check for shortcuts, then pass them on. Does anything propagate back up to the window if no widget handles them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll paste a summary of how gtk_window_key_press_event() works:

```
gboolean
gtk_window_propagate_key_event (GtkWindow        *window,
                                GdkEventKey      *event)
{
  gboolean handled = FALSE;

  focus = window->focus_widget;

  while (!handled)
    {
      GtkWidget *parent;

      handled = gtk_widget_event (focus, event);
      focus = gtk_widget_get_parent (focus);
    }

  return handled;
}

static gint
gtk_window_key_press_event (GtkWidget   *widget,
                GdkEventKey *event)
{
  GtkWindow *window = GTK_WINDOW (widget);
  gboolean handled = FALSE;

  /* handle mnemonics and accelerators */
  if (!handled)
    handled = gtk_window_activate_key (window, event);

  /* handle focus widget key events */
  if (!handled)
    handled = gtk_window_propagate_key_event (window, event);

  /* Chain up, invokes binding set */
  if (!handled)
    handled = GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (gtk_window_parent_class)->key_press_event (widget, event);

  return handled;
}
```

This basically means:

1. See if the key is appropriate for a mnemonic (i.e. labels that have underlines) or an accelerator (from GtkAccelGroup).
2. Starting from the focused widget and going up the container hierarchy, see if some widget handles the keypress.
3. Pass on the keypress to the parent class of GtkWindow.  The closest parent that handles that is GtkWidget, and it does so by dealing with bindings (from gtk_binding_entry_add()).

As you said, simply doing g_signal_connect() to the key-press-event signal of GtkWindow will give you *all* keypresses that happen when that window is focused.

Try doing g_signal_connect_after() instead.  This will effectively add another fallback to the sequence above - it means, "run my signal handler after the default one".  Note that you'll be catching *all* unhandled keypresses (e.g. if someone presses a function key that your app doesn't handle), so don't assume that the only thing that gets through to your handler is coming from your barcode scanner.

Comment: Remember to return TRUE from all other handlers as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to configure your barcode scanner to send say ALT digit (or similar) rather than digit for the bar code's number this will help in this filtering

Comment: No scanner defaults to ALT, and no end user knows how to configure a scanner. Relying on timing and checksum to distinguish barcodes from other input works fine.